# If I have a double quote ' " ' in my text it shows up in the pdf as \textquotedbl{}

Tags: lyx, punctuation, minted

I am new to latex. I am running xubuntu 14.04. I am using Lyx 2.0.8. I can write, compile to pdf then view the pdf. Unfortunately, if I have a double quote ' " ' in my text it shows up in the pdf as \textquotedbl{}.

Any clues? If I use the same tex file in Kile or others, this does not happen. An offending file is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
Here is a lua file

\begin{minted}{lua}
  require "copas"
  require "md5"
  dofile("/dev/shm/eserver/SaveLoad.lua")
\end{minted}

Here is a c file.
\end{document}
```

Below is a copy from the pdf output.

```
Here is a lua file.
require \textquotedbl{}copas\textquotedbl{}
require \textquotedbl{}md5\textquotedbl{}
dofile(\textquotedbl{}/dev/shm/eserver/SaveLoad.lua\textquotedbl{})
Here is a c file.
```

Here is the expected output [added by cfr]:

[image: expected output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please modify your code snippets to create an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001).

Comment: There must be some packages you're loading or additional macros in the preamble that are the cause of the problem behavior. Hence the request that you provide a fully compilable example that generates the problem.

Comment: This file as shown compiles. It exhibits the problem.

Comment: There is no file which could be compiled to exhibit the problem. Please read the link Mico provided in the first comment and follow the instructions there to create a proper MWE.

Comment: cfr, I checked the MWE link and, as far as I can see, I am providing the MWE. I broke up the file into text and preamble to clarify. I don't see how I can make the text to compile much smaller.

Comment: It doesn't clarify it. It is much better to put it together. It is not complete. You cannot compile that code if you copy-paste it into a TeX editor without first adding stuff to make it compilable. For example, you have `\end{document}` but where is the beginning of this environment? And presumably you are using LaTeX, so you need to specify a class. But it is most likely that doing that is not enough to reproduce the problem. I kind of doubt that `minted` does this by default. That would be weird.

Comment: I have edited your question to provide a complete MWE. I've also added what I take to be the expected output. I obtained this by compiling the completed MWE. Please edit the MWE so that compiling it reproduces the problem you are seeing. Otherwise, all anybody can really say is that something you've not shared is responsible for the problem, we know not what.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I know, I have shared everything. I get that output using Kile, Texworks etc., just not with LyX. Did you use LyX?

Comment: You have clearly not shared yet one or more rather crucial items. The code, as amended by @cfr, is now compilable, *but it's not generating the problem behavior you say you are encountering*, viz., the appearance of the `\textquotedbl{}` strings. There must be something out there, which you haven't revealed so far, that is causing the problem behavior. What's keeping you back?

Comment: As I said, I am new to this. In LyX the preamble and document class are in Document-->Settings. I did a cut and paste of the "good" code from your site to LyX and it requires to move pieces of it to the aforementioned settings. After I do this I get the same result as before...but only in LyX.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that in LyX I have to put the minted part of the file into a [ctrl]+[L] box. Only then does it work.

Comment: How I get a down vote when the problem is solved beats me.

Comment: Can you post the problematic .lyx file and your solution .lyx file? I would like to take a look to see if there is a bug in LyX.

Comment: scottkosty, I have had a glass of wine, so I will reply tomorrow. Can I attach files or do I have to do the 4 spaces thing?

Comment: files are OK with me since the question has already been answered

Comment: @scottkosty Files cannot be attached here. Are you suggesting the OP email them to you or post them elsewhere?

Comment: @cfr thanks. I suppose the best then is that the OP past them here. .lyx files are just text files after all.